# Как сделать onItemSelected в ListView?

Tags: listview, java

Я сделал, чтобы в ListView показывало список файлов из папки. Так вот мне нужно, чтобы при выборе какого-то файла в другом активити вставлялось его содержимое (текст) и  название файла.

Comment: И где конкретно возникла проблема? Код в студию

Comment: @minecrafter_MLS, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.